# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.twilio.Twilio

Tags: web, twilio, classloading

For some reason Twilio SMS works only in a public static void main function as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hVpI.png). When I try to move it to a JSF environment shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpTOy.png) it gives me an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aahY5.png) saying "NoClassDefFoundError" which means the class was not found in the classpath. The strange this both the working and not working twilio are in the same project which puzzles me. I'm unsure of how to solve it.

**Working Code**

```
package twilio;

import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class TwilioMSG {
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "myAccSid";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "myAuth";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    Message.creator( new PhoneNumber("+myNumber"), new PhoneNumber("+TwilioNumber"), "I am having Java class").create();
    }
}
```

**Code with error**

```
package controllers;

import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber; 

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class PhoneController {
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "myAccSid";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "myAuth";

    public PhoneController() {
    }

    public void testSMS(){
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        Message.creator( new PhoneNumber("+myNumber"), new PhoneNumber("+TwilioNumber"), "I am having OS class")
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

```
[#|2019-01-13T19:58:46.428+0800|WARNING|glassfish 5.0|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(2);_TimeMillis=1547380726428;_LevelValue=900;|
  #{phoneController.testS}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twilio/Twilio
javax.faces.FacesException: #{phoneController.testS}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twilio/Twilio
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:119)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:330)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:870)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1418)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twilio/Twilio
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twilio/Twilio
    at twilio.TwilioMSG.WhatsApp(TwilioMSG.java:19)
    at twilio.TwilioMSG.SMS(TwilioMSG.java:28)
    at controllers.PhoneController.testS(PhoneController.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
|#]

[#|2019-01-13T19:58:46.431+0800|SEVERE|glassfish 5.0|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(2);_TimeMillis=1547380726431;_LevelValue=1000;|
  javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twilio/Twilio
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:330)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:870)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1418)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twilio/Twilio
    at twilio.TwilioMSG.WhatsApp(TwilioMSG.java:19)
    at twilio.TwilioMSG.SMS(TwilioMSG.java:28)
    at controllers.PhoneController.testS(PhoneController.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
|#]
```

I am using Glassfish as my server and IntelliJ just for extra information

Comment: Please paste your code and error into your question rather than use images.

Comment: A 'JSF' project is a basic java web project. This question is in no way JSF related.

Comment: Are you building this project using some build tool (like pom) or manually using class path?

Answer (score 0):

Usually `NoClassDefFound` errors are related to missing libraries at runtime.

In your case, probably in your local setup you have it in your classpath, running your main method successfully.

Now when moving to a JSF environment, you have a server involved, so you have to pay attention in a couple things:

1. Is the dependency JAR available on a shared folder/classpath on the server?
2. Is the dependency being package along your WAR or EAR?

So unpack and check you WAR ans check the classpaths to see If your dependency is available, and provide it in the classpath or WAR/EAR.

Comment: The dependency Jar is not on a shared folder with the server and it is not packaged along my WAR. The dependency is stored inside my IDE, intellij Idea and my artifact, WAR is both in a separate package. I'll try to provide it in the war and hope for the best.